Why is Starlink able to deliver gate-to-gate Internet in planes while other systems are only working above 10,000 feet?
I read on https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2024/09/free-starlink-internet-is-coming-to-all-of-uniteds-airplanes/ (mirror):

United says it will start testing Starlink equipment early in 2025, with the first use on passenger flights later that year. The service will be available gate-to-gate (as opposed to only working above 10,000 feet, a restriction some other systems operate under), and it certainly sounds like a superior experience to current in-flight Internet, as it will explicitly allow streaming of both video and games, and multiple connected devices at once. Better yet, United says the service will be free for passengers.

Why is Starlink able to deliver gate-to-gate Internet in planes while other systems are only working above 10,000 feet?

not downvoting or saying off-topic or anything, but if it doesn't get answered here it might be worth trying Aviation. It could very well be regulatory differences on the FAA or FCC side.  If the answer is a Space Exploration answer I'd expect it to come down to being more likely to have line of sight to a Starlink or few since its constellation is much more numerous than ViaSat's or other competitors'.

@ErinAnne - It seems more likely to be the latter reason, as FAA apparently doesn't have an altitude restriction, their info page says only "You may use the WiFi connection on your device if the plane has an installed WiFi system and the airline allows its use." Meanwhile I have seen comments or statements to the effect that some airlines have a minimum altitude in order to better meet customer expectations. But I haven't seen any official statements about it.

It's probably because of how Starlink satellites are positioned in orbit and how they utilize their technology and knowledge. As of now, I don't have a backed-up answer to this question to looking forward to answers.

The main limitations are technological or based on being conservative about safety.
Some systems are ground-based and line of sight and so can only reliably work once the airplane is high enough to be within line of sight of a ground station. This does not apply to satellite internet so long as there are enough satellites in the constellation.
Below 10000 feet is often seen as the critical part of a flight, below which the flight crew are forbidden from all activities besides those essential for the safety of the flight. In cases where it is not an essential limitation, turning off the wifi is likely part of this- if there is any significant chance that wifi could interfere with the safety of flight, it should not be operated under 10000 feet.
There is no regulation saying specifically that wifi cannot be used below 10000 feet. But in-flight wifi systems need to be approved by the FAA. If the manual for a given wifi solution says that it must not be turned on under 10000 feet then that rule must be followed even if the rule appears unnecessary in hindsight.
Aviation is a slow-moving field that is very conservative when it comes to safety. In aviation terms, it was practically yesterday that airlines begin allowing personal electronic devices to be used below 10000 feet at all, much using their radios to communicate with aircraft systems! A long history of electronic devices not interfering in a dangerous way with avionics will likely continue to lead to increased laxness of rules around them.

The only thing Starlink related is the Starlink receiver on the plane, which then feeds into the plane's existing WiFi system, which is unrelated to Starlink. For your answer to be correct there would have to be something different about the interface between the Starlink receiver and the plane's Wi-Fi system which is somehow different than other interfaces such as the interface between the ViaSat receivers used on other United airplanes and the same Wi-Fi system. If United upgraded their Wi-Fi and that's what makes it allowed, presumably they would do the same on all of their planes.

the first paragraph sounds pretty authoritative but the remainder of the answer doesn't seem to have any information specific to the actual differences questioner wanted to know about

@StevePemberton I am doubtful there are any real technical differences to existing space-based wifi technology. Besides almost certainly more satellites. But rules aren't a free thing to change. Pretty much any change an airliner wants to make is expensive. I also suspect that some of these systems could have specific operating limitations that they not be operated below a certain altitude. Certainly ground-based ones do- some of Gogo's older products only work above 10000 feet due to firmware disabling the system below that altitude even though they have since upgraded their network to...

operate down to 3000 feet. 10000 feet is a very arbitrary limit but other services probably can't go gate to gate just for lack of sufficient satellite coverage.

Welcome to 330,000 feet!

@uhoh Uhoh. I'm gonna have to file an ASRS for violating 14 CFR § 91.211. :(

Some systems, specifically Gogo Inflight's earlier systems, use air-to-ground links, and therefore require altitude to get a good propagation path to the towers.
Gogo's air-to-ground system was an evolution of the old Airfone in-flight calling system. They're very similar to a cell phone network with the antennas pointed to the sky. Exploiting the line-of-sight of an aircraft at cruise altitude makes the system significantly more economical, using only 200 cell sites versus the 200,000 terrestrial cell sites in the US.
